# Can I remove hand typed lagged variables when using dynlm?

Tags: r, time-series, regression, lag

I am running an ARDL time series regression and was wondering if I need to include hand-typed lagged variables in the regression formulas when I use the dynlm() function. When i add the lagged variables, I have high multicollinearity but when I remove them, the results looks perfect!

I was wondering if dynlm() already includes lagged variables and typing them in would be redundant.

I hope to get some help